# ModelState invalid in KendoUI date sent to ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm using ASP MVC and KendoUI. Data are sent in json format. I'm getting ModelState error from KendoUI grid update where the according to debugger the ModelState ErrorMessage - **"The value '/Date(1361499139623)/' is not valid for FirstAvailableDate."**

Here's the print screen of my firebug POST
[image]

How to resolve this? I'm currently doing ModelState.Clear(); ...sad...

Comment: Try applying dateformat for that date proprty of model

Comment: model at the ASP side or the model at the kendoui javascript side? i'm using KendoUI with ASP Wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the project is missing the "[kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies)" script.

Comment: i did include this js file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up formating the date using javascript before posting it back to ASP MVC Controller.

Here's my javascript:

```
    function toISOString(d) {
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var date = d.getDate();
        return year + '-' + month + '-' + date;
    }

    function toMVCDateTime(d) {
        return d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + padzero(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' + padzero(d.getUTCDate()) + 'T' + padzero(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' + padzero(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + padzero(d.getUTCSeconds()) + '.' + pad2zeros(d.getUTCMilliseconds()) + 'Z';
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "TimeSheet/GetWeeklyHistoricalTimeSheets",
        type: "POST",
        //data: { date: utcDate.toISOString() },
        data: { date: toISOString(utcDate)},
        success: function (response) {
            htmlFactory(response);
        }
    });
```